# Contacts evaluated/accepted with "No Re-Entry" journey settings in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a quick question about the "No Re-Entry" journey settings in Journey Builder. 
I configured my journey with a DE as entry source and set a recurring schedule (daily basis). Journey Settings are configured as "No Re-Entry".

If a contact is being EVALUATED but not ACCEPTED in the journey at day 1, will he be re-evaluated the next day (day 2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, unless a contact is accepted and indeed enters the journey, this person will still be evaluated in the future. So in your example, contacts who are evaluated and not accepted, are not excluded from future evaluations.

Comment: Hi Lukas, thanks for your answer, that is exactly what I needed to know!